# Is it possible to make a multine textbox in a Silverlight 4 DataForm?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I know that you can set a textbox as multiline in SL4 by setting the AcceptsReturn field to true. However, if you insert this into a DataField and DataForm, the textbox always shows as a single-line textbox, even if I change the VerticalAlignment to Stretch.

How can I make it multiline?

Answer (score 0):

Use `EditTemplte` and put `Textbox` as your `DateTemplate`.
As you already said, set the `Textbox AcceptReturn` to true, and that's it.

Sample of DisplayTemplate and EditTemplte you can watch here : (@23:00~)
http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/data-controls/dataform-control

Please update on how it went.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm already using the EditTemplate. If I put the Textbox in on its own, it works fine. However, I want to use it within a DataField so that I get the label and tooltip icon - at this point I lose the multiline textbox.